# Glut Open GL object wont animate

Tags: c++, opengl, glut

My polygon wont move, I tried many things and i think `glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);`or `glutMainLoop();` wont do their job. So first picture stay the same. There is no animation.

```
float x=0;
float y=0;
float b=0;

void displayCB(void) 
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    kvadrat();
}

void kvadrat()
{
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
    glColor3f(1, 0, 0); glVertex2d(0.5-x, 0.5-y);
    glColor3f(1, 0, 0); glVertex2d(0.5-x, -0.5-y);
    glColor3f(1, 0, 0); glVertex2d(-0.5-x, -0.5-y);
    glColor3f(1, 0, 0); glVertex2d(-0.5-x, 0.5-y);
    glEnd();

    Sleep(1999);
    glFlush();
    x=x+0.01; // I modified this value so it will always be between 0.5 and -0.5,     
             //this is just example
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int win;

    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGB);
    glutInitWindowSize(800,600);

    win = glutCreateWindow("Elementi");

    glClearColor(0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0);

    glutDisplayFunc(displayCB);
    glutKeyboardFunc(keyCB);
    glutMainLoop();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be moving the position only a very small increment every two seconds, so the image appears to be static, but it's not, it's just changing very slowly. Try taking out the Sleep(1999) and see whether your animation works any better.

If you need to animate over time, it is better to instead use glutGet(GLUT_ELAPSED_TIME) to figure out how much time has elapsed since the last frame and use that to scale your deltas.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed problem with `glutPostRedisplay();` // Inform GLUT that the display has changed

Comment: Indeed you must use glutIdleFunc to get a continous call. glutPostRedisplay is only called in presence of a redisplay event.